# Spring Freemarker render "includes" individually

Tags: spring, path, include, freemarker

I have a freemarker template (index.ftl) with an include (page1.ftl and page2.ftl) inside it:

```
this is the sample content on index.ftl
<#include "/pages/page1.ftl">
<#include "/pages/page2.ftl">

blablabla contents here
```

In my spring environment, I extended the class "AbstractTemplateView" and override "renderMergedTemplateModel" method which calls doRender like this:

```
protected void doRender(Map<String, Object> model, String viewName,     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    logger.debug("start doRender");
    try {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        String templatePath = templateService.getTemplateLocation();
        config.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File(templatePath));
        Template template = config.getTemplate(viewName);
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=" + template.getEncoding());
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        template.process(model, out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String message = format("cannot render template <{0}> due to IOException: {1}", e.getMessage());
        logger.error(message, e);
        throw new NestedServletException(message, e);
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I set the directory for the includes individually for page1.ftl and page2.ftl? Is it possible ? "setDirectoryForTemplateLoading" method only sets the default directory for the templates. Any includes will be looked up relative to this directory.

The context of this problem is that I will load the include. But if I cannot find the includes , it will look up to another directory.

Example FTL say (index.ftl):

```
 FREEMARKER MAIN

 <#include "page1.ftl">
 <#include "page2.ftl">
```

I tried the multiloader and it seems to be working on the index.ftl. it will try to resolve to the directories ive define. but how can I make it resolve say like different directory path for page1.ftl and page2.ftl? Is it possible? Its giving me errors when one of the include is not present.

Answer (score 1):

`setDirectoryForTemplateLoading` is only a convenience method which passes a corresponding `FileTemplateLoader` to `Configuration#setTemplateLoader`. You probably want to combine several `FileTemplateLoader`s into one `MultiTemplateLoader` and pass this template loader to `Configuration#setTemplateLoader`, e.g.:

```
import freemarker.cache.*; // template loaders live in this package
...
FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("/tmp/templates"));
FileTemplateLoader ftl2 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File("/usr/data/templates"));
TemplateLoader[] loaders = new TemplateLoader[] { ftl1, ftl2};
MultiTemplateLoader mtl = new MultiTemplateLoader(loaders);
cfg.setTemplateLoader(mtl);
```

(taken from [the FreeMarker documentation about loading templates from multiple locations](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#autoid_41))